# Spark Accumulator not working

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, accumulator, hortonworks-sandbox

I want to get the number of closed orders from [this](https://github.com/dgadiraju/data/tree/master/retail_db/orders) data using accumulators. But it is giving me incorrect answer, just zero(0). What is the problem? I am using Hortonworks Sandbox. The code is below. I am using spark-submit.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('closedcount')
sc   =  SparkContext(conf=conf)
rdd = sc.textFile("/tmp/fish/itversity/retail_db/orders/")
N_closed = sc.accumulator(0)
def is_closed(N_closed, line):
  status =(line.split(",")[-1]=="CLOSED")
  if status:
    N_closed.add(1)
  return status
closedRDD = rdd.filter(lambda x: is_closed(N_closed, x))
print('The answer is ' + str(N_closed.value))
```

But when I submit it, I get zero.

```
 spark-submit --master yarn closedCounter.py
```

[image]

#### UpDate:

Now, when I change my code it works fine. Is this the right way to do it?

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('closedcount')
sc   =  SparkContext(conf=conf)
rdd = sc.textFile("/tmp/fish/itversity/retail_db/orders/")
N_closed = sc.accumulator(0)
def is_closed(line):
  global N_closed
  status =(line.split(",")[-1]=="CLOSED")
  if status:
    N_closed.add(1)

rdd.foreach(is_closed)
print('The answer is ' + str(N_closed.value))
```

[image]

### Second Update:

I understand it now, In Jupyter Notebook, without Yarn, it gives me the correct answer because I have called an action (count) before checking the value from the accumulator.
[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with Hadoop or HDP, most likely, but why aren't you just `closedRDD.count()`?

Comment: It is "not working" because you don't execute any action. Also accumulators inside transformation are not reliable.

Comment: @cricket_007, I know I can use count(). But I want to try out accumulators.

Comment: @user8371915, but the same code gives me an answer in a Jupyter notebook in my Stand Alone Spark Installation. Can you please give me more elaboration?

Comment: Maybe because local Spark is just that - local. Not distributed over YARN and accumulated

Comment: I can guarantee that _the same code_ does not give you any other answer.

Comment: @user8371915, I have included my Jupyter Notebook code and the answer.

Comment: So it is not _the same code_ after all, is it?

Comment: @user8371915, right, it has the action collect()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Computations inside transformations are evaluated lazily, so unless an action happens on an RDD the transformationsare not executed. As a result of this, accumulators used inside functions like map() or filter() wont get executed unless some action happen on the RDD

https://www.edureka.co/blog/spark-accumulators-explained

(Examples in Scala)

But basically, you need to perform an action on `rdd`.

For example

```
N_closed = sc.accumulator(0)
def is_closed(line):
    status = line.split(",")[-1]=="CLOSED"
    if status:
        N_closed.add(1)
    return status

rdd.foreach(is_closed)
print('The answer is ' + str(N_closed.value))
```